# How I remove to ubuntu from windows7

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, uninstall

I used dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. And I want to remove Ubuntu from my PC. I tried [these steps](http://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/)

And I have two problems:

1. After I deleted my Linux partition, I tried to expand other spaces. When I clicked on them, the "extend volume" option was passive.
2. I don't have the Windows installer disc, so I tried to create a Windows repair disc. But when I clicked "create disc" button, I got an error message. It said that "there is no media in the device."

Comment: See [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533) Answers there detail alternatives to a Windows repair disk for writing the Windows boot loader to the MBR. And as [Emerson Hseih says](http://askubuntu.com/a/143482) (citing [Tanner's comment](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533#comment199520_143482)), "If you are using an extended partition, you might have to remove the big extended partition to make the space unallocated." If that doesn't help, please [edit] with a screenshot of Disk Management. (You can post it somewhere like http://imgur.com and add a link.)

Comment: is your windows partition on the right or left

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this, for your second question, it's got instructions on how to do it without a windows recovery disk... and how to do it with, and a whole lot more information as well.
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/grub

Is the deleted partition now unallocated space?  There is a scenario I can think of that would cause this, if the partition you deleted is not side by side with the partition you want to expand.  If this is the case I'm not sure how to go about doing exactly what you want...  you can turn it into a logical drive, you can probably wipe some partitions between the space and the partition you want to expand (if their not hidden.)  There are probably other maybe better options I'll keep an eye open.

UPDATE: Okay found it here http://www.disk-partition.com/resource/add-unallocated-space-to-system-partition-windows7.html you have to move the unallocated space.  Beware I have not tried this application and do not know how it works, I'm just guiding you to the page.

Answer (score 0):

After I deleted linux partition, the grub was deleted. When I restart my pc, I got an error via "grub rescue."

The solution :

I installed a linux version(.iso file) on another pc. I booted a usb using nbootin program with .iso file. After I connected the usb on pc, I started my pc. I installed new ubuntu. My grub is alive now with new ubuntu version.

Answer (score -2):

You would need a disk partition utility to make the windows partition the active boot partition. You should be able to delete the partition you have used for linux and extend it into windows. Do you recall what disk format you used when installing Ubuntu? It was probably EXT3 or EXT4 which windows will not read natively.